# PHP Not Working With Proxy Pass

Tags: php, proxy, apache2

**QUESTION**

It seems that my php pages are not loading through proxypass set up on my master Apache server. What change do I need to make in order to get php pages to load through my proxypass?

I tried this question on Ask Ubuntu but some suggest I try the question here. This is the exact post from that forum.

Ask Ubuntu Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003434/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu-server

**ORIGINAL POST**

This I would imagine is going to be a simple answer. (It wasn't) I have Apache2 running on my Ubuntu server but it seems PHP is not installed. When I try to load a php page it does not load properly.

Example: http://urbanturtles.servegame.com/ (My Site)

At first I thought the php module was simply not loaded but when I try to run `sudo a2enmod php` but it did not work and I get this error:
`ERROR: Module php does not exist!`

Thanks for help in advance!

**EDIT**

After trying to load a simple PHP page to show the php version I have gotten a new error trying to load the page. that error is visible here: http://urbanturtles.servegame.com/version.php . This makes me think I have more of an Apache issue than a php issue. I have a main Apahce sever that proxys all incoming traffic to each server inside my network. The Apache config for the main server looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName MaxKulik.net
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.MaxKulik.net"
        ServerAlias "MaxKulik.net"
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName MaxKulik.net
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.MaxKulik.net"
        ServerAlias "MaxKulik.net"
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
        ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.5/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.5/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName USI
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.UrbanTurtles.servegame.com"
        ServerAlias "UrbanTurtles.servegame.com"
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.28/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.28/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the php error that I was getting: 
[image]

Comment: The error isn't visible at that link, just a phpinfo(); statement. Please reproduce the error message here, so your question may still be useful later

Comment: I added the php error to the end of the question. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one `ServerName` directive in your VirtualHost. The directive should match the primary FQDN of your site, all other FQDNs should be `ServerAlias`.

```
ServerName www.urbanturtles.servegame.com
ServerAlias urbanturtles.servegame.com
```

Remove the `ServerName USI` directive, it's not a FQDN.

If you have multiple `ServerName` directives and Apache decides to use the wrong one your VirualHost will not match.

Comment: Regarding the PHP setup: That belongs into the config of your Apache on 192.168.1.28.

Comment: Gerald, do you mean that `ServerName` belongs to the Apache config on the web server that is 192.168.1.28?

Comment: And I made the change by getting rid of the `ServerName` directive and it seems to have no effect.

Comment: It seems my php proxy error is no longer persistent but my php pages are still not loading.